# I want to hide text box on a button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide text box on a button click, the problem is that button is already hidden which will be displayed after changing the text in that text box

Comment: Please show us your code. What have you tried so far? We can't do much with limited information.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Did you try to consult a shaman ?

Comment: Add your code to get help!

Comment: Pleae read: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for you however like the others said it is very hard to answer if you do not post code :P

```
document.querySelector('#yourinput > location > etc').onkeypress = function() {
    //If our text input detects a key press do this function
    /*
    //Optional*
    if (document.querySelector('#yourinput > location > etc').value == "MagikWord"){
    document.querySelector('#yourbutton').style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
    document.querySelector('#yourbutton').style.display = "none";
    }
    //With this additional condition your button wont show up until you type "MagikWord"
    */
    document.querySelector('#yourbutton').style.display = "block";
}
document.querySelector('#yourbutton').onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector('#yourinput > location > etc').style.display = "none";
}
```